# Add dynamic labels and textboxes from a checkedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedListBox, that contains names of some chargingstations i have in a SQL database. I have filled the checkedListBox with the station names, and i would like that if you check an item in the box, a label with the text "Km to "+itemsChecked.StationName would appear just below the checkedListbox, as well as a textBox, where one would enter the kilometers to the station.
It's being used to create a new charging station, and the kilometers are the cost of the edge to the next station. 
I've tried something like this:

```
private void stationCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (BetterServiceReference.Station itemsChecked in stationCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
        {
            var lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lblAuto" + itemsChecked.StationId;
            lbl.Text = "Km to " + itemsChecked.StationName;
            lbl.AutoSize = true;
            lbl.Location = new Point(33, 462);
            lbl.Name = "label1";
            lbl.Size = new Size(35, 13);
            tabPage7.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
```

Only it doesn't actually create a label.

Comment: Are you sure you are entering your `foreach` loop? I don't know what "BetterServiceReference.Station" is, but try using something like `foreach(var itemChecked in stationCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)`.  Also, FYI, you are setting the name value twice...

Comment: I used 'foreach(object itemsChecked in stationCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)' before, with the same result. I have also tried without the double Name values.

Comment: I have seen people doing it with a table in WPF, but I can't find any solution for Win Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample program, and it seems to work fine for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "Testing";
                lbl.Location = new Point(125, 125);
                this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }
    }
```

Some things to check / try:

- **Make sure the location of your label is not behind some other control!!**
- Use `var` / `object` instead of "BetterServiceReference.Station"
- Is `tabPage7` the name of your form? Try using `this.Controls.Add(lbl);`

I will also warn you that your function will **not** remove the labels once an item is unchecked.  Also, as-is, it will only create **one** label in **one** spot for any checkbox checked.  It's going to take a bit of work to implement what you are trying to do; as the other answer suggested, you may be better off toggling controls between visible / invisible.

But, hopefully my answer will help you dynamically create a label, and creating the textboxes will be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the label in the designer and make it Visible="False". Then in your code, make it Visible="True" as needed. Same with the textbox.

Comment: You can add controls without the designer.

Comment: I have tried it.
`foreach (BetterServiceReference.Station itemsChecked in stationCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                int i = 1;
                var lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Name = "edgeLabel" + i;
                lbl.Text = "Km til " + itemsChecked.StationName;
                lbl.Visible = true;
                tabPage7.Controls.Add(lbl);
                i++;
            
            }`

The label thats set to Visible=False is called edgeLabel1 (and 2 and 3), but the new label i create here shows up in the top corner, and does not replace my previous label

Comment: foreach (BetterServiceReference.Station itemsChecked in stationCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                edgeLabel1.Text = "Km til " + itemsChecked.StationName;
                edgeLabel1.Visible = true;
                edgeTextBox1.Visible = true; 

This works, but only for the first label and textbox